# Login to Mongo after removing root

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I had set pass for user root. Then I removed user root. Now I cannot log in to server. What should I do?

How can I disable user authentication again?

removing admin.* files removes authentication, but is it a better way?

Comment: Suggest asking this on dba.stackexchange.com as this doesn't seem to be a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

can't you edit `/etc/mongod.conf` and remove `auth=true` line ?

Then readd your mongo users and put the auth back.